# VirtualBox vs Qemu vs VMWare

Tags: virtualbox, rdp, qemu, vnc

Пытаюсь организовать себе комфортную работу через удаленные рабочие столы. Хотел бы узнать, через что это сделать лучше?

Попробовал:

```
qemu-kvm + vnc - Картинка сыпется, работать невозможно. Скролинг в браузере как слайд шоу
qemu-kvm + spice - Уже лучше, но скролинг в браузере все равно как слайд шоу.
VirtualBox + VNC - Показал самый лучший результат.
```

Почему такая разница между работой qemu + vnc и virtualbox + vnc? И есть ли смысл пробовать xrdp ?

О железе: Гигабитный роутер, мощная хостовая машина, подключаюсь к ней с macbook.

Comment: по моему самый шустрый x2go, а самый шустрый видеодрайвер в vmware

Comment: Хорошо, попробую его тоже. Но мне все равно интересно, почему такие разные результаты работы с VNC через virtualbox и qemu.